# ng 10: how to run tests for all projects

Tags: angular

according to the docs of [ng test](https://angular.io/cli/test), `ng test` (without any project) should run all tests:

> When a project name is not supplied, it will execute for all projects.

This does not work in ng `10.0.13`. When a [defaultProject](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#overall-json-structure) is specified in `angular.json`, only these tests are executed.
This used to work in older versions (ng 9.x).

Is there a way to run the tests of all projects, even when a `defaultProject` is specified?
Is this maybe a bug, or a breaking change that I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround, we removed "defaultProject" in `angular.json`. Now all tests are executed.